Setting up REST API Call from Synapse Web activity and receive a Invoking endpoint failed with HttpStatusCode - '404' error
I am attempting to setup a Web Activity in Azure Synapse to call a Semantic Model Refresh for power bi via a REST API.  However, when I try to debug it I get the following error.

I have setup the web activity as follows:
URL:  https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/gr...{pipeline().parameters.groups}/datasets/@{pipeline().parameters.DatasetGUID}/refreshes
Method:  POST
BODY:
{"type":"full","commitMode":"transactional","applyRefreshPolicy":"true"}
Authentication:  Service Principal:  My Service Principal
Authentication Reference Method: Inline
Tenant:  TENANT
Service Principal ID:  ID
Service Principal Credential Type:  KEY
Resource:  https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api

If you look on the activity itself, on the output box, does the fully formed URL match the one you are expecting? (After the parameters have been parsed.)


